# GitLab CI: How to fail on new compiler warnings

Tags: gitlab, compiler-warnings, static-analysis, gitlab-ci, static-code-analysis

We are trying to get an old legacy code base under control while simultaneously developing new features. Currently the code compiles with a hell of a lot of compiler warnings and warnings from static code analyzers. For that reason it is not uncommon that code introducing new warnings reaches production simply because the new warning got lost in the shuffle.

Currently we are using Jenkins for nightly builds and make the build fail on new warnings. However, when Jenkins detects the new warnings the code was already merged a few hours ago. So we would like to not only shorten the feedback cycle but also ensure to only merge changes that do not introduce new warnings.

As far as I know it is possible to trigger a Jenkins build on a push to GitLab. But Jenkins can only compare the count of warnings to the previous build. But we would need to compare to a build of a different branch.

Can GitLab CI or a combination of GitLab EE and Jenkins somehow be configured to detect if a merge request introduces new warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime tools got developed that allow a workflow which is not perfect but comes quite close.

Jenkins has the [Warnings Next Generation Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Next+Generation+Plugin) which can compare the warnings found in one Jenkins job to the warnings found in another Jenkins job. So we set up a job to compile our develop branch each time a new commit is pushed to it. We then use the results as baseline. Another job that gets triggered for each merge request in GitLab then uses this baseline to determine the new warnings introduced by the merge request.

This works reasonably well.

Comment: I second using Jenkins rather than GitLab for this; we’re using both, but Ulli Hafner’s stuff is much better for nagging developers informatively.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is possible but that's rather an open-ended question that will depend a lot on how long a build takes and how you will compare the outcomes.

You don't have to run only the checks on the branch you have checked out. You may set up two jobs in parallel that run tests on current branch and the develop branch, pass them as [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) to a third job and compare them there.

You may want to store the state of a build on your develop branch and [download the artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/jobs.html#download-the-artifacts-archive) to your current job and compare it against the local results. You could also store them in a database, on a file server or wherever else it's comfortable.

Finally you may try an external code quality tool like SonarQube which has greater insight into what's new and what's old.

Comment: So there is no intelligence integrated into GitLab and there are no add-ons I could install. I have to do it myslef?

Comment: @sigy correct, gitlab is a huge and amazing piece of software but CI, is just CI.